# Is there a tool to display the structure of a file?

Tags: file-format, viewer

Over the years, thousands of binary file formats have been defined. Is there a tool that can display an arbitrary file format in a human-readable (and maybe even editable) way?

Specifically, I'm looking for something that can read a "format description" and build an editor/viewer for this format (I don't want to be limited to the built-in formats).

Kind of [file(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) but should give all the details instead of just an overview.

Comment: Obviously not possible without the format description. I'm wondering - how would such a format description file look like?

Comment: Since binary formats almost always require a codec or somesuch, are you expecting this to support plugins or to delegate reading as soon as the appropriate tool is determined? For example, discovering an xcf could launch the GIMP, or conceivably supply a window for GIMP to edit in. If you don't mean images, then are you looking for something more specific, like regular or irregular grids of data...?

Comment: @JanDvorak: A DSL with scripting

Comment: @PhilH: I want to see the file structure itself, not the image. Or maybe the editor/viewer could show me image data as a picture plus the decoded data next to it.

Comment: @PhilH I guess reading the header + marking the data chunk as such should do.

Comment: @AaronDigulla this smells of a plugin system (lots of small programs) with delegated GUI to a common core.

Comment: I don't think such a tool exists, but if you decide to build it, let me know ;-)

Comment: ETL tools do something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load.  There are tools that take formal descriptions of bit patterns and extract the bits; think of this is a binary data parser.  The ones I know about are used to analyze binary machine code files, but the concept isn't special to such files. See http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/toolkit/, especially the discussion on SLED.

Comment: I don't think this question is non-constructive. If you don't think so either, click Reopen.

Comment: Same here. I'm really surprised that such a tool doesn't already exist. We have (a few) hex editors out there but nothing that goes a step beyond that?